# Line and a plane parallel and we know two points, determine the plane

Tags: linear-algebra

We know the equation of the line: $$\frac{(x-3)}{2}=y+4=\frac{z}{5}$$ and two points which are $P=(1,3,4)$ and $Q=(3,6,10)$.
$P$ and $Q$ are on the plane and the line is parallel to it. I need to determine the equation of the plane.

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Slightly More than a Hint: Two vectors parallel to the plane are $\langle 2,1,5\rangle$ and $\langle 3-1,6-3,10-4\rangle = \langle 2,3,6\rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** add the vector of the line to one of the points to get the third point...